# MvxImageView shows image only the first time a activity is opened

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I have an Xamarin.Android app with an fragent with

`<Mvx.MvxImageView with local:MvxBind="ImageUrl LogoUrl" ...>`

The first time I go to the activity, the image is displayed as expected, but if I go back and forth the image is gone. Even though ImageUrl have the same value. This happens on iOS as well where I use:

```
set.Bind (imageView).To (vm => vm.SuperMerchantLogo);
```

Comment: Is there some Mvx trace output in the debug output window?

Comment: What version of mvvmcross are you using? This should be fixed in latests versions

Comment: I am using latest version of `MvvmCross` and I have the same problem. When I go to page in second time - image doesn't displayed. I overrided `OnDraw` method in inheritance class from `MvxImageView`. When I navigate to page in second time this control has `ImageUrl`, but `Drawable` is null.